# Scaling the second axe on a histogram with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to have a second axe on my histogram, with the pourcentage corresponding to each bin, like if I used normed=True. I tried to use twins, but the scale is not correct.

[image]

```
x = np.random.randn(10000)
plt.hist(x)
ax2 = plt.twinx()
plt.show()
```

Bonus point if you can make it work with log scaled x :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.hist` returns the bins and the number of data in each bucket. You may use these to compute the *area* under the histogram, and using that you may find the normalized height of each bar. `twinx` axis can be aligned accordingly:

```
xs = np.random.randn(10000)
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
cnt, bins, patches = ax1.hist(xs)

# area under the istogram
area = np.dot(cnt, np.diff(bins))

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.grid('off')

# align the twinx axis
ax2.set_yticks(ax1.get_yticks() / area)
lb, ub = ax1.get_ylim()
ax2.set_ylim(lb / area, ub / area)

# display the y-axis in percentage
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
frmt = FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{:>4.1f}%'.format(x*100))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(frmt)
```

[image]

Comment: not sure if you ll read my comment but how do oyu get those colors ?